# Client registration with Qt + pjsip

Tags: qt, sip, pjsip

I'm trying to make a sample application with pjsip in qt.
I think I added pjsip to Qt correctly because I can see the methods in the library. But I don't know how to use them. Can anyone help me create an account with pjsip?

This is my .pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

DEFINES -= UNICODE

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

# Absolute address of the .lib file
LIBS += $$PWD/3rdparty/pjlib/lib/pjlib-i386-Win32-vc14-Debug.lib
LIBS += $$PWD/3rdparty/pjlib-util/lib/pjlib-util-i386-Win32-vc14-Debug.lib
LIBS += $$PWD/3rdparty/pjmedia/lib/pjmedia-i386-Win32-vc14-Debug.lib
LIBS += $$PWD/3rdparty/pjnath/lib/pjnath-i386-Win32-vc14-Debug.lib
LIBS += $$PWD/3rdparty/pjsip/lib/pjsua-lib-i386-Win32-vc14-Debug.lib

# Absolute address of its header files (if any)
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/3rdparty/pjlib/include
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/3rdparty/pjlib-util/include
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/3rdparty/pjmedia/include
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/3rdparty/pjnath/include
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/3rdparty/pjsip/include
```

This is the pjsip methods

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdFwS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdFwS.png)]

should I use pjsip_regc_create() method ? is there an example on how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the vidgui sample app https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/tree/master/pjsip-apps/src/vidgui